# PyQt: How to refresh label on one window with push button on another one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

Hello dear Users of stackoverflow

**Introduction:**
I am kind of new to Python and want to build a touch GUI for my Raspberry Pi with PyQt5. Therefore, I use the QtDesigner to build up .ui files on Windows 7. After that, the files are translated to .py files using "pyuic5 -x file.ui -o file.py" in the LXTerminal of the Pi.

**My GUI:**
I need to build up one output window (MainWindow) with a label and a push button, which opens up another window (I chose Dialog) for input. The input window has a spin box to set the value and a horizontal slider for bigger value steps. At the bottom of the window is a push button, which sets the spin box value as global variable and closes the Input window again.

**The problem:**
I want the push button of the input window that closes this window to also refresh the output label of the MainWindow, so that it shows the new value.

**Pictures:**
I am not allowed to embed Pictures of my GUI yet, so please see the following links.

[MainWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9fQ0.jpg)

[InputWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYHrY.jpg)

[InputWindow with Connections between slider and spin box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkR0T.jpg)

**My Code:**
The following code is a simple example and has everything working except the refresh of the Label. Please help me to get this work, even if it might be very simple for advanced and professional developers. I spent days on trying and googling for this and got lots of more complicated things working.

Best wishes,

RaspiManu

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

value = 0

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(890, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 500, 250))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 370, 500, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        ############
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenInput)
        ############

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Value"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to input window"))


    ##############################
    # Show second window for input

    def OpenInput(self, MainWindow):
        Dialog.show()

    ##############################


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(889, 598)

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 170, 471, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(33)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(209, 360, 471, 61))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 460, 271, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        ############
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.CloseAndRefresh)
        ############

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 40, 471, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.spinBox.setValue)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Back to first Window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Value"))


    #######################################################
    # Close second window and refresh label on first window

    def CloseAndRefresh(self):
        global value
        value = self.spinBox.value()
        print(value) #checking input

        ##################################################
        # The refresh of the outputting label on the     #
        # MainWindow should be started at this position. #
        ##################################################

        Dialog.close()

    #######################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dia = Ui_Dialog()
    dia.setupUi(Dialog)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

value = 0

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(890, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 500, 250))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 370, 500, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        ############
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenInput)
        ############

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Value"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to input window"))


    ##############################
    # Show second window for input

    def OpenInput(self, MainWindow):
        Dialog.show()

    ##############################

    # +++    
    def labelText(self, MainWindow, value):
        self.label.setText(str(value)) 


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(889, 598)

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 170, 471, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(33)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Dialog)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(209, 360, 471, 61))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 460, 271, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        ############
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.CloseAndRefresh)
        ############

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 40, 471, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.spinBox.setValue)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Back to first Window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Value"))


    #######################################################
    # Close second window and refresh label on first window

    def CloseAndRefresh(self):
        global value
        value = self.spinBox.value()
        print(value) #checking input

        # +++
        ui.labelText(MainWindow, value)

        ##################################################
        # The refresh of the outputting label on the     #
        # MainWindow should be started at this position. #
        ##################################################

        Dialog.close()

    #######################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dia = Ui_Dialog()
    dia.setupUi(Dialog)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Answers that show only code without explaining anything or making comments in the code are not of good quality. I recommend you read [answer]

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)
I knew it would be 2-4 lines of code but I couldn't get it working. This made my day :D